# Is there a way to change the icon of a page to 'loading/busy'?

Tags: jquery, css

I know the cursor can be altered to indicate a page loading:

```
$('body').css( 'cursor', 'progress' )
```

for instance... But I'm looking for a way to put the page itself in a loading stage, like the browser is doing when a page is loading, on the spot where normally the favicon would be displayed. Is there a way to change the status of that to waiting?

Comment: anyway google and firefox will give you that cursor, why you want it again?

Comment: @charan: I'm processing stuff on the server while the user has full control over the page... if they close the page before the server is done the user might lose changes made. There is a 'leave site' prompt when a user moves away, but I'd like to have a little indicator the server is busy... the cursor is too in-your-face, I now use a div on the page, but it's nicer to have it in the place of the favicon. Neither Firefox nor Google change this icon/cursor on an Ajax call processing